# vba let user select a range on worksheet from ms access

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010

The sub RangeSelectionPrompt below let the user to select a range of cells.
The code below works only if this code is on Excel files.

I would like to know to execute this code inside of MSAccess. I want to capture the user selected range and do data manipulation.
Is it Possible or  did I smoke to much.

From Access I know how to lunch Excel, detect how many WBK are open, navigate in the workbook,.... 
Form Excel I know how to create an add-in , connect to a DB and transfer the data after user selection but this is not what I want.

```
Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to create an `Excel.Application`, then call `.InputBox` on that.

Comment: Did try but, Did not Succeed. I will put the code tonight from home.

Comment: Did fix it ! the bug was Set xlWB = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select . See the entire code below. Thanks Comintern

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim rng As Range


Sub GetUserSelection()
    On Error GoTo ErrExcelinstance

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set xlWB = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook              ' the bug was Set xlWB = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select

    RangeSelectionPrompt

    Exit Sub

ErrExcelinstance:


    Select Case Err.Number

    Case 429

        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No Workbook Open"
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWB = Nothing


    Case Else

        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWB = Nothing
        MsgBox Err.Number & "  " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear

    End Select

End Sub


Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()
    On Error GoTo RangeSelectionPrompterr:

    Set rng = xlApp.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

    MsgBox "The cells selected were " & rng.Address

    Exit Sub

RangeSelectionPrompterr:


    Select Case Err.Number



    Case 424

        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "User did not perform selection"
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWB = Nothing


    Case Else



        Set rng = Nothing
        MsgBox Err.Number & "  " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear

    End Select


End Sub
```